# Two or more properties in a class that have value from the same variable are in relation

Tags: javascript, c#, oop

So in my JS project, there was a situation when a class had two properties in which the values were obtained from the same variable. Upon trying to change the first property, somehow to second property also had the same changes.

Then I thought that there was something wrong with my code, so I created a new test file to see if my algorithm was doing something wrong. And sadly the same thing happened when I tried on simple classes.

Here is the code:

```
class ClassWithValue {
    constructor(input) {
      this.value = input;
    }
  };
      
    class ClassWithTwoValues{
      constructor(class1, class2) {
      this.class1 = class1;
      this.class2 = class2;
    }
  };
      
      var variable = new ClassWithValue(12);
      
      //document.write(variable.value);// Returns 12
      
      var variableWithTwoValue = new ClassWithTwoValues(variable, variable);
      
      variableWithTwoValue.class2.value += 10;
      
      document.write(variableWithTwoValue.class2.value + " ");// Returns 22

      document.write(variableWithTwoValue.class1.value);// Also returns 22
```

Then I tried to replicate it in C#, because I believed It was still me who didn't understood well JS OOP. But sadly the results were the same.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassWithValue var1 = new ClassWithValue(12);
            ClassWithTwoValues var2 = new ClassWithTwoValues(var1, var1);
            var2.class1.value += 10;
            Console.WriteLine(var2.class1.value);// Returns 22
            Console.WriteLine(var2.class2.value);// Also returns 22

        }
    }


    public class ClassWithValue
    {
        public int value { get; set; }

        public ClassWithValue(int input)
        {
            this.value = input;
        }
    }

    public class ClassWithTwoValues
    {
        public ClassWithValue class1 { get; set; }
        public ClassWithValue class2 { get; set; }

        public ClassWithTwoValues(ClassWithValue value1, ClassWithValue value2)
        {
            this.class1 = value1;
            this.class2 = value2;
        }
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong and how can I overcome this issue?

Closing:

- For JS: Hemant Halwai suggested two great solutions. And after some digging I also found that Object.assign() can be used as a third solution.
- For C#: Sadly I wasn't able to find as simple as the JS example solution. Some suggest to create a method from scratch who copy the object while others suggest the use of Object.MemberwiseClone Method.

Comment: Read up on the difference between [Value and Reference types](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/value-and-reference-type-in-oop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS code example, variable is a reference value, and you are passing variable as a parameter to ClassWithTwoValues.

- So internally class1 and class2 are pointing to the same reference (**address in memory**)
- So even when only class1.value is changed, class2.value also reflects the same value.

Quick fix:

1. Using spread operator

   `var variableWithTwoValue = new ClassWithTwoValues(variable, {...variable});`
2. OR Using Json Conversion

   `const secondvariable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable));`
   `var variableWithTwoValue = new ClassWithTwoValues(variable, secondvariable);`

**Both methods will point new memory reference for for class2**